# Error with MapServer WMS GetMap request, how to fix it?

Tags: wms, mapserver, getmap

I got this message when I call GetMap on a MapServer WMS

```
msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Missing required parameter SRS
```

What causes that problem?

Comment: Your GetMap request does not contain the mandatory SRS parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is that the service is expecting a **SRS** parameter and you have not supplied one.

If you are making a GetMap (and GetFeatureInfo) request with  WMS versions 1.1.1 or below, you must pass the coordinate reference system to the WMS Server (in this case MapServer, but the same is true for all WMS servers) using the `SRS` parameter.

Like **SRS=epsg:27700&** in the below GetMap request:

```
http://.../cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms? 
  service=WMS&
  version=1.1.1&
  request=GetMap&
  layers=GBR_BGS_625k_BA&
  format=image/png&
  SRS=epsg:27700&
  bbox=0,0,700000,1300000&
  width=350&
  height=650&
  styles&
```

For WMS version 1.3.0 the parameter name changes to `CRS` (spelling of parameter names is not case sensitive, just using capitals for emphasis here).

Like **CRS=EPSG:4326&** in the below GetMap request:

```
http://.../cgi-bin/BGS_GSI_Geology/wms?
 REQUEST=GetMap&
 SERVICE=WMS&
 VERSION=1.3.0&
 LAYERS=IND_GSI_2M_Thrusts&
 STYLES=default&
 FORMAT=image/png&
 BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&
 TRANSPARENT=TRUE&
 CRS=EPSG:4326&
 BBOX=6.0,67.0,36.0,97.0&
 WIDTH=650&
 HEIGHT=650&
```